# Can't open a Cmder terminal on VSCode (only powershell) since last update

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmder

Since one of the last updates of VSCodem, I am unable to open a Cmder terminal, even with cmder specifically indicated as my terminal client.

settings.json

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\Cmder\\Cmder.exe",
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {"CMDER_ROOT": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\Cmder"},
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows" : ["/K","C:\\laragon\\bin\\cmder\\vendor\\init.bat"],
```

It only opens a powershelll terminal and cmder doesn't even appear on the dropdown options list on the add terminal button.

If I manually launch the cmder in windows and them press the CTRL+Ç, it will focus on the external window and will not open a terminal inside vscode.

Anyone had this problem? I can't figure it out... microsoft again doing what it does! I don't want powershell, I want cmder...

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I figure it out, you now have to have a profile for each terminal.
It is explained how to add a profile in here: https://dev.to/andrewriveradev/how-to-setup-cmder-in-vscode-in-2021-3nkc